# Android: Compare two Maps keys, if keys are equal create new object

Tags: java, android

I have two `LinkedHashMap<String, MyType>` where keys can be common (say key from first map can be "key" and key from second map can be also "key". I need to compare this two maps and when keys are equal I want create new object where `firsMapEntry.getValue()` `secondMapEntry.getValue()` are attributes of new object [ `new MyObject(firsMapEntry.getValue(), secondMapEntry.getValue())` ]. Maps are in `Collection` so I iterate through collections.

Here's my source:

```
firstIterator = firsCollection.iterator();
secondIterator = secondCollection.iterator();

    while (firstIterator.hasNext() && secondIterator.hasNext()) {
        Map<String, MyType1> firsMap = firstIterator.next();
        Map<String, List<MyType2>> secondMap = secondIterator
                .next();

        firstMapIterator = firstMap.entrySet().iterator();
        secondMapIterator = secondMap.entrySet().iterator();

        while (firstMapIterator.hasNext() && secondMapIterator.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String, MyType1> firstEntry = ((Map.Entry<String, MyType1>) firstMapIterator.next());
            Map.Entry<String, List<MyType2>> secondEntry = ((Map.Entry<String, List<MyType2>>) secondMapIterator.next());


           // Here I was trying to compare keys but unsuccessfuly

          // if keys are equal create new object

        My Object object = new MyObject(firsEntry.getValue(),
                    secondEntry.getValue());
                      Map<String, MyObject> map = new LinkedHashMap<String,MyObject(); map.put("key", object);

        }
    }
```

Return type of method is `List<Map<String, MyObject>>`.
I don't know if my method is effecient, but how to compare two keys and create new object from values. Every help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Where are you comparing the keys in your above code? Have you removed that piece and replaced with the comments?

Comment: Yes where are comments, there I want compare keys. I had sth. like if ( firstkey.equals(secondKey)  { ... but as result a I got always only one Map

Comment: What if you have map entries `1, 2` in the first map and `2, 1` in the second? You use `LinkedHashMap` so it appears that insertion order is significant to you; hence the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Map.Entry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) has a method called `getKey()` , use this to get the key.

Since your key is a String use , `Object.equals()` to [compare them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) , do not use '==' ,so:

```
    if(firstEntry .getKey().equals(secondEntry .getKey())){
    //they are equal
    }
else{
    //they are different
    }
```

Comment: I've done it but as result I've had only one Map, I've tought that it doesn't work. Maybe there's a bug somewhere.

Comment: Thank you guys finally I've found mistake in source.